# Triple Monitor Issue 3x ASUS VC239H (DVI, HDMI, VGA) monitors with AMD Radeon R9 270x 4GB (DVI, DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort)

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, displayport

#### Problem:

If I connect two monitors to the graphics card via DVI to DVI one of the monitors doesn't turn on. It's not a broken port or broken cable as I've tried them individually and they work fine.

According to http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/170 I should be able to connect all 3 monitors how I have it setup because all 3 monitors are the same, they're all 1920x1080 which isn't excessive in terms of resolution so that can't be the issue.

When I connect or disconnect the DVI cable Windows makes the "da ding" noise to tell me that a device has been connected/disconnected but nothing happens because of it. You can see the detection state:

[image]

#### Current Setup:

- DVI-D (Single Link) to DVI-I (Dual Link) (Monitor 1, working)
- HDMI to HDMI (Monitor 2, working)
- DVI-D (Single Link) to DVI-I (Dual Link) (Monitor 3, **not** working)

#### AMD Radeon Sapphire R9 270x 4GB Ports:

- 2x DVI-Dual Link
- 1x HDMI
- 1x DisplayPort

#### ASUS VC239H Monitors:

- 1x DVI-D Ports
- 1x HDMI
- 1x VGA

I'm sure this should be able to be done, but if not...I know I should avoid using VGA to DisplayPort (I have an Active Adaptor from my old monitors) that never had HDMI or DVI ports

What would be the best adaptor to use DVI to DisplayPort

- DVI (Monitor Side) to DisplayPort (GPU Side)
- HDMI (Monitor Side) to DisplayPort (GPU Side)

I would assume HDMI to DisplayPort would be the best one to pick, but I'm not 100% sure and what about the adapter being active or passive? Is there any need for an active adaptor, if so what would be the benefits?

Comment: After you have connected the third monitor and Windows plays the device connected sound does the third monitor show up in Catalyst Control Center at all? I see some reports of multi-monitor setups on R9 270x cards having monitor autodetection issues but manual configuration in CCC worked.

Comment: @rakslice Nope, it doesn't show up in either of them. See: http://i.imgur.com/uuTlNG0.png, it does however show up in Device Manager: http://i.imgur.com/s1wwRkd.png

Comment: Most Radeon cards I have encountered **require** you yo use a DP port connector for monitor 3 and beyond. Did you check your cards manual to see if your card is an exception to this rule?

Comment: Well, if you look at http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/170 it says my card should be able to allow 2x dvi & 1x hdmi no problem as all 3 monitors are identical. If it's not the case, what adaptor would be best? HDMI to DP or DVI to DP? Also Active or Passive?